# how to add a dot-directory to mercurials hgignore

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, hgignore

I have used mercurial for some time now and never had any problems using hgignore.
Now I have created a new project using eclipse, which added a `.metadata` directory.
I seem to be unable to ignore the `.metadata`.

```
nils@yavin $ hg status
? .metadata/.mylyn/repositories.xml.zip
? .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/37/509db4063df7001f14dbbfe704ff2c4e
...
```

My `.hgignore` looks like this:

```
syntax: regexp
/\.metadata/.*
\.metadata/.*
glob:.metadata/*
glob:.metadata/.mylyn/repositories.xml.zip
```

As you can see, I tried some things... I even tried adding one file directly, but it did not work.
Is there any magic involved when dealing with dot-directories? Or am I simply stupid today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove everything and leave:

```
glob:.metadata/*
```

The first line `syntax:regexp` in your .hgignore is making hg treat all subsequent lines as regex, including the one with glob:.metadata/*