# mercurial hgignore does not ignore directory

Tags: mercurial, metadata, glob, hgignore

The same question has been asked before but the solutions don't work for me.

I want to instruct Mercurial to ignore a folder named .metadata, by adding it to the .hgignore file. Here is my .hgignore file:

```
glob:.hgignore
glob:.hgignore~
glob:.metadata/*
```

I have successfully tested that ignoring .hgignore and .hgignore~ works. If I remove the first two lines and run hg status, they show up. If I include the first two lines and run hg status, they disappear. But it doesn't work for the .metadata folder. The syntax above is the one reported in the solution referenced below. It doesn't work for me. I also tried glob:.metadata/.

A temporary workaround is not to use Mercurial on the workspace, where the .metadata files are.  ;-)

Any suggestions welcome, thanks!

EDIT: SOLUTION And so it appears that this works:

```
glob:.metadata
```

it's also simpler and therefore prettier. Thanks to greut for pointing it out.

[how to add a dot-directory to mercurials hgignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288093/how-to-add-a-dot-directory-to-mercurials-hgignore)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a dot-directory to mercurials hgignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288093/how-to-add-a-dot-directory-to-mercurials-hgignore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got this in mine:

```
syntax: glob
.metadata
```